# Android Firestore "Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend" error on LTE (fine with WIFI)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Ever since yesterday (2021.10.25) my app does not connect to firebase when connected to LTE.
I've tried this on multiple devices using multiple different phone network providers.

To be more specific, in the code below, we go to the "**Log task unsuccessful**" case.

```
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Version").document("MinVersion");
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                      //Do stuff here
                    }
                } else {
                    //Log task unsuccessful
                }
            }
        });
```

When I turn on wifi, firebase connects immediately.

Potentially useful logs:

```
W/Firestore: (23.0.4) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
    
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

(However, internet connection is fine - once the app is loaded up, ads work fine, web browser work fine etc - only firestore does not work)

What could be causing this? I live in South Korea and there was a 40 minute service outage in one of our largest service providers yesterday... could this have to do with something? Maybe the firestore team temp blacklisted Korea for servicing? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Add `Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());` in the else part. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo This is the error : "com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline."

Comment: So most likely you don't have a healthy internet connection, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo That's the thing. Internet speed is fine, and this is affecting all users using LTE not just me. Therefore, internet connection is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update people who might stumble on here, as of 2021.10.27 (2 days after issue first happened), the issue has resolved itself. All users are able to use firestore even on LTE (as it's supposed to).

**App has not been updated at all.**

I'm assuming South Korean mobile service providers have updated firewall to allow firestore services again...